# Alarm Manager shows notification everytime

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have made an android application that displays a notification message at a particular time (say 6:15:00 pm) of the day. I have used the **Calendar** along with **AlarmManager** class for this purpose.

However, when I installed the app on my phone to test it, it showed me the message/notification at the specified time but continues to show the same at any time..I mean the notification keeps on coming throughout the day in my phone even though I have set the time for it in my app.

Here is my code
1) Activity class

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 { 

  private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

} //end onCreate

 }
```

2) Receiver

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;

   public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
   context.startService(service1);

   }

 }
```

3) Service class

```
   import android.app.Notification;
   import android.app.NotificationManager;
   import android.app.PendingIntent;
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.IBinder;


 public class MyAlarmService extends Service 

  {
 private NotificationManager mManager;

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
 {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
 }

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
   super.onCreate();
}

   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
   super.onStart(intent, startId);

   mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

   Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

   intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

   mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

I have added both service and receiver in manifest.xml file. Please can anyone tell me what should I do to display the notification only once during the entire day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason was the onCreate method was called multiple times and so your alarmManager.set was called multiple times.  For example, whenever the screen orientation is changed, that activity is destroyed and a new activity starts by onCreate() method.  So every time you rotate the screen that activity will be destroyed and a new activity starts by onCreate() method and alarmManager.set was called again.

You may save a state member in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) method. Android calls this method whenever the screen is rotated, and that given bundle bundle would be passed to oncreate(Bundle bundle).   In your onCreate, check the Bundle is null before try to call alarmManager.set.

Comment: Yes I get your point..Can you suggest what changes should be done to my code to achieve this?

Comment: thanks this worked! I have not got any notification message for the entire day except for the time I specified...hopefully it will keep showing the same...if any problems I will comment over here

Comment: @ParthDoshi i am facing same problem can you tell me how did you check bundle in on create.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I did not ever use BroadcastReceiver like

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
```

So I doubt whether the usage of BroadcastReceiver is wrong, usually we use BroadcastReceiver as below:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mypackage.START_ALARM" ></action>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver> 

Intent i = new Intent("mypackage.START_ALARM");
```

Comment: Yes i changed my Intent as well as the receiver in the manifest but still its not working...I get notification more than once during the day....It should be only at one particular time of the day and not any other time

Answer (score 1):

try this its working fine for me :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    ca.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I tried that code it was working fine not sure why it's not working for u

Comment: Is it because I have added it inside the onCreate() method due to which the Activity gets restarted everytime. Can u post your entire Activity class code over here?

Comment: try this start service from actvity and set the alarm in service.